# Javascript remove array objects with duplicate properties while keeping the latest occurance

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates

I've searched a lot for this but couldn't find anything that match my requirement.

I want to remove all the duplicates but keeping the **last entry** not the first.

The array is already presorted I don't want to mess with sorting

So it looks like this :

```
[{
    name:"Joe",
    status:"foo1" },
  {
    name:"Joe",
    status:"foo2"},
  {
     name:"Vani",
    status:"foo5"
  }]
```

The expected output looks like:

```
  [{
    name:"Joe",
    status:"foo2"},
  {
     name:"Vani",
    status:"foo5"
  }]
```

I'd be thankful if someone can help me!

Comment: Perhaps try reversing the array, then try any other method that keeps the first value. You can then reverse it back

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: The array is already pre-sorted I don't want to mess with sorting! , I will add this above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of ES6 `Map`. As from [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The `Map` object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

```js
const data = [
  { name:"Joe", status:"foo1" },
  { name:"Joe", status:"foo2" },
  { name:"Vani", status:"foo5" }
];

const removeDupes = (arr, map = new Map()) => {
  arr.forEach(o => map.set(o.name, o));

  return [...map.values()];
};

console.log(removeDupes(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let arr = [{ name:"Joe", status:"foo1" }, { name:"Joe", status:"foo2"}, { name:"Vani", status:"foo5" }]

let op = arr.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  op[inp.name] = inp
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Comment: It is not guaranteed that values in array returned by `Object.values()`  will preserve the same order as in input array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using simple `forEach`,

```
const arr = [{ name:"Joe", status:"foo1" }, { name:"Joe", status:"foo2"}, { 
    name:"Vani", status:"foo5" }];

let result = {};
arr.forEach((val) => { result[val.name] = val; });

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't actually keep the order, it amends the object at the initially found index

You could amend it to look like this:

```js
const data = [
  { name:"Joe", status:"foo1" },
  { name:"Vani", status:"foo2" },
  { name:"Joe", status:"foo3" }
];

const removeDupes = (arr, map = new Map()) => {
  arr.forEach((o, i) => map.set(o.name, {...o, order: i}));

  return [...map.values()].sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
};

console.log(removeDupes(data));
```

Or perhaps do something more simple like:

```js
const data = [
  { name:"Joe", status:"foo1" },
  { name:"Vani", status:"foo2" },
  { name:"Joe", status:"foo3" }
];

let newData = [];
data.forEach(x => {
  newData = newData.filter(y => y.name != x.name);
  newData.push(x);
});

console.log(newData);
```

I'll let someone else figure out a more performant solution...

Answer (score 0):

```js
// remove duplicate while preserve order
array.filter((row, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, i).findIndex((l) => l === row) === -1)
// change `l === row` to your own comparison logic
```

In your case:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name:"Joe",
    status:"foo1"
  },
  {
    name:"Joe",
    status:"foo2"
  },
  {
    name:"Vani",
    status:"foo5"
  }
];

const duplicateRemoved = data
  .toReversed()
  .filter((row, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, i).findIndex((l) => l.name === row.name) === -1)
  .toReversed();
```